# Translating LAT, LONG to actual Screen X,Y coordinates on a Equirectangular Map Projection in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, geolocation, map-projections

I am doing a little project on Geo Locations. I need to highlight certain cities on an a map that is in `equirectangular projection`. I have got the `LON` `LAT` values for those cities, I need to find a way to translate those values to actual x,y coordinates on screen that will work with any size of map (with equirectangular projection). I have found a code but that does it for `Mercator projection`. Any Clue ?Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is quite simpler than doing Mercator projection, try this function:

```
public function getXY(lat:Number, lng:Number):Point
{
  var screenX:Number = ((lng + 180) * (mapWidth  / 360));
  var screenY:Number = (((lat * -1) + 90) * (mapHeight/ 180));

  return new Point(screenX,screenY);
}
```

`mapWidth` and `mapHeight` should be the width and height of your Map's Image that you are using. This function will return you the translated coordinates from LAT LON to X, Y of your screen with respect to your map size.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Let me try it. Is it for the equirectangular projection ?

Comment: Great!! looks like it works but the plotting is a little off. I think i will figure it out.

Comment: Just make sure you are using an 'standard' Equirectangular projection map and that you don't have any extra space included around the map like empty white space or blue ocean !